# UITableViewDelegate not working getting an error (Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in UITableView in swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The data of `namesArray` and `descriptionArray` getting from previous VC.

I have set the `delegate` and `datasource` of my tableview but I am getting an below error

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
var namesArray: [String] = []
var descriptionArray: [String] = []
@IBOutlet weak var tblProjectList: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(namesArray.count)

    self.tblProjectList.delegate = self
    self.tblProjectList.dataSource = self
}
```

`namesArray` has data but why at `self.tblProjectList.delegate = self` app got crashed.

Comment: Please double check your `UITableView` outlet is connected properly

Comment: @Kuldeep yes outlet is connected properly

Comment: @SanjayMishra Please check your **Outlet** of UITableView not connected with multiple ViewControllers.

Comment: tblProjectList is the only thing that can be unwrapped on that line, so it is nil. Put a breakpoint on that line to prove it. Then, it's either connected wrongly or not at all. Remove the connection and reapply it.

Comment: check every variable you force to unwrap. Check your connections, do not forget to delegates. It's so fundamental mistake, for first 3-4 times follow to tutorials will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your IBOutlet is connected to TableView. Sometimes it gets disconnected.

The process to check:

- Open storyboard and controller side by side and check.
- In case it is connected, in storyboard check if TableView delegates are connected.
- Also check the TableView hierarchy. In storyboard it might be out of scope to get connected.

Answer (score 0):

Remove and create the tableview outlet once again.

Comment: Then place a breakpoint just before the crash and try po(tblProjectList) in debugger console. If it doesn't print the table information then you are doing something wrong. Try to add the tableview again and create its outlet and then try.

Answer (score 0):

Define `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` in your `UIViewController`

[image]

Comment: I have already added it class ProjectsListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting

"Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Than there is some issue with cell identifier, array index not set proper.
You can check this both scenario.